# Связка множественного числа с единственным

Tags: словосочетания, единственное-множественное-число

Мы предпочитаем говорить

```
Машины без номеров
Дома без крыш
Люди без голов
Столбы без фонарей
```

вместо

```
Машины без номера
Дома без крыши
Люди без головы
Столбы без фонаря
```

С другой стороны, мы говорим

```
Машины без руля
Предложения без точки
Рассказы без конца
```

вместо

```
Машины без рулей
Предложения без точек
Рассказы без концов
```

Есть ли тут какая-нибудь закономерность?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я думаю, **закономерность есть**.

1. Мы можем сказать: *Здесь все машины без номеров, дома без крыш, люди без голов, а столбы без фонарей.*  В этом случае  мы **обобщаем ситуацию**, наблюдая конкретные явления. Например: *И у этой машины  номера нет, да здесь все машины без номеров!*
2. Но в других ситуациях мы идем **в обратном направлении**:  *Машины без номера  обслуживаться не будут. Вот у вас, я вижу, номера пока нет.* Здесь падежная форма имеет  качественно-типизирующее значение (термин из синтаксиса), мы обобщаем предмет по конкретному признаку.
3. **Парные варианты**:

Стали  встречаться дома без крыш. Вообще-то такие дома без крыши мне не нравятся.

У него все рассказы без концов. Его рассказы без конца уже надоели.

Машины без руля – это в будущем.  А я уже видел несколько машин без рулей.

В этом офисе все люди без голов.  Интересное выражение – люди без головы. Это какие же, ты что имеешь в виду?

Comment: Спасибо, здорово!